# Compute size of the normalizer of a subgroup of $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

If a subgroup $H\subset S_n$ is generated by a single $m$-cycle, i.e there is some $c_m=(a_1~a_2~...~a_m)$ such that $H=\left<c_m\right>$. Using orbit-stablizer, $$\left|\operatorname{N}_{S_n}(\left<c_m\right>)\right| = \frac{\left|S_n\right|}{\left|\{ \left<\sigma c_m\sigma^{-1}\right>:\sigma\in S_n\}\right|}$$

The conjugation $\sigma c_m\sigma^{-1}$ is an $m$-cycle and every $m$-cycle in $S_n$ appears in this form for some $\sigma\in S_n$. Note that there are $\phi(m)$ number of $m$-cycles in each $\left<\sigma c_m\sigma^{-1}\right>$, while there are $$\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m}$$ many $m$-cycles in $S_n$. Then $$\left|\{ \left<\sigma c_m\sigma^{-1}\right>:\sigma\in S_n\}\right|=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m\phi(m)}$$ and $$\left|\operatorname{N}_{S_n}(\left< c_m \right>) \right|=(n-m)!\phi(m)m.$$

In general for an element $\sigma\in S_n$ such that there are $d_1$ copies of subcycles of length $m_1$,and $d_2$ copies of subcycles of length $m_2$,...,and $d_k$ copies of subcycles of length $m_k$(for example $(12)(34)(567)$ has $2$ copies of subcycle of length $2$, and $1$ copy of subcycle of length 3), orbit-stablizer in a similar way gives $$\left|\operatorname{N}_{S_n}\left(\left<\sigma\right>\right)\right|=\left(n-s\right)!\phi\left(\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,...,m_k)\right)\prod_{i=1}^k\left(m_i^{d_i}\right)\prod_{i=1}^k\left(d_i!\right)$$ where $$s=\sum_{i=1}^km_i^{d_i}.$$ Just note that the $\prod (d_i!)$ is the overcount for the orbit as disjoint cycles of the same length may commute.

The case where $H$ is generated by a single permutation is handled above completely. However, the several generators case confuses me. If $\sigma_1,\sigma_2\in S_n$ are two permutations, for example, how can one express $\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_1,\sigma_2\right>)\right|$ in terms of $\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_1\right>)\right|$ and $\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_2\right>)\right|$?($\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are not necessarily disjoint.)

In general how can one express $\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_1,\sigma_2,...,\sigma_r\right>)\right|$ in terms of $\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_1\right>)\right|$,$\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_2\right>)\right|$,...,$\left|\operatorname{N}(\left<\sigma_r\right>)\right|$?

Comment: You trivial observation is not correct in general. It would be wrong for example if you had more than one cycle of the same length. If the cycles are not disjoint then you cannot say much at all.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right. They also need to have different length. I will remove it anyways.